# Getting a single FileMaker record ID in PHP

Tags: php, filemaker

I'm trying to write to an existing record in FileMaker, using PHP.

I have tried the following to find and edit the record, but it simply doesn't write the new data:

```
$fm_ = new FileMaker(FM_FILE, FM_HOST, FM_USER, FM_PASS);

$request = $fm->newFindCommand('INFO');
$request->addFindCriterion('ID', '==' . $_SESSION['on']);
result = $request->execute();

$records = result->getRecords();

foreach($records as $record) {
    $record->setField('Confirm', $_SESSION['confirm']);
    $result = $record->commit();
}
```

Any idea why this isn't writing?

Comment: You need to make a 'newEditCommand' and execute that. I suggest checking out the chapter on the PHP API in Filemaker's guide on custom web publishing. Here is the link for version 16 but it should be relevant. fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/16/en/fms16_cwp_guide.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a newEditCommand and execute that. This would probably work:

```
$fm_ = new FileMaker(FM_FILE, FM_HOST, FM_USER, FM_PASS);

$request = $fm->newFindCommand('INFO');
$request->addFindCriterion('ID', '==' . $_SESSION['on']);
result = $request->execute();

$records = result->getRecords();

foreach($records as $record) {

    $editRequest =& $fm->newEditCommand('INFO', $record->getRecordId() );
    $editRequest->setField('Confirm',$_SESSION['confirm']);
    $result = $editRequest->execute();
    if (FileMaker::isError($result)) {
        echo "<p>Error: " . $result->getMessage() . "<p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I did use this subsequently, but had the same result. Turned out the FileMaker db allowed create, but not edit!